# Printing an iframe and surrounding content when iframe is larger that a printer's paper size

Tags: html, printing

I have an application on one domain that displays content from another application from a different domain. The iframe gets dynamically resized similar to the method described [here](http://solidgone.org/Set-IFRAME-height-based-on-size-of-remotely-loaded-content) to prevent the iframe from having any scroll bars in it. The problem I'm having is that when the page is printed, if the iframe is bigger than a printer's paper size, content from the iframe is not printed. I would like the iframe to print on multiple pages, not get truncated. I have set the page-break-inside css property to auto in the print css, but that didn't seem to do anything. Can an iframe span multiple pages when printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done except maybe for a fancy "Poster" printer driver that can split huge output to multiple pages. That would require installation on the client side, of course.

Can't you print the IFrame's contents alone? Without a surrounding page?

Comment: That is a possibility. I've been looking around for a solution, and this solution keeps coming up. Before I implement this less than ideal solution, I would like to know if the ideal solution is impossible. Why can't a page-break be inserted into the middle of an iframe. Is an iframe any different than a paragraph or div? Can't those span multiple pages when being printed?

Comment: An iframe is an entirely independent document within a document, which is why I guess the page-break won't work - it would have to intelligently split up the surrounding page *and* the document in the iframe. Probably too much to ask any browser right now.